# linking two lists together with an iterator function in python

Tags: python, python-2.6

i have two lists, both with 128 items:

a= [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
b= [6.4, 53.8, -5.2, 7.1, ...]

i have to run list b through two checks:

1. is b[n]>50.0
2. is b[n]<0

if check1 is true, than b[n]=b[n]-50, AND a[n]=a[n]+1
if check2 is true, than b[n]=b[n]+100, AND a[n]=a[n]-1

i can't figure out how to tie the two items in each list together so that a change in list b[n] triggers a change also in list a[n]

using this example, after running these lists through the 2 checks:

a= [0, 2, 1, 3, ...]
b= [6.4, 3.8, 94.8, 7.1, ...]

i'm only weeks into programming with python and i have absolutely no previous experience with coding. i've been reading about iterators, maps, for loops, etc but i can't seem to get the language right for this sequence.

it seems easy but i'm stuck!

thanks,

joel.

Answer (score 4):

Produce pairs of corresponding items from the two lists with `zip` and process each pair. You can use a generator comprehension to get all the processed pairs, and `zip` again to get lists back.

```
def process(a, b):
    if b > 50:
        a += 1
        b -= 50
    elif b < 0:
        a -= 1
        b += 100
    return (a, b)

def process_all(as, bs):
    # Notice the '*' here. 'zip' takes multiple arguments;
    # the '*' forces evaluation of the generator, and expands the resulting
    # sequence into several arguments.
    return zip(*(process(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(as, bs)))
```

Comment: thanks karl. all of these answers help me buck up on my python language skills, but i'm going to go with the simpler answer below, as it's more in line with what i was dreaming up myself. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is there anything wrong with just

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if b[i] > 50.0:
        b[i] -= 50.0
        a[i] += 1
    elif b[i] < 0.0:
        b[i] += 100.0
        a[i] -= 1
```

Comment: this is sweet! i actually broke this into two separate functions and printed out both lists before either, inbetween, and after both functions just so i could stare at the lists to see how they were behaving. this works well, and it's simple (which means i can explain it), so i'm going to run with this code. thank you hugh!

Comment: """If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea."""